# Configuring apache directories in puppet

Tags: puppet

When I configure an apache from puppet, i get  in apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

How can I change that? My host are in /var/otherdir/ and won't work.

my puppet init file

```
class apache
{
  package
  {
    "apache2":
      ensure  => present,
      require => [Exec['apt-get update'], Package['php5'], Package['php5-dev'], Package['php5-cli']]
  }

  service
  {
    "apache2":
      ensure      => running,
      enable      => true,
      require     => Package['apache2'],
      subscribe   => [
        File["/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load"],
        File["/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf"],
        File["/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf"]
      ],
  }

  file
  {
    "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load":
      ensure  => link,
      target  => "/etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load",
      require => Package['apache2'],
  }

  file
  {
    "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf":
      ensure  => present,
      owner   => root, group => root,
      source  => "/vagrant/puppet/templates/vhost",
      require => Package['apache2'],
  }

  exec
  {
    'echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/fqdn.conf':
      require => Package['apache2'],
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a file section for `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` which requires package Apache2

Get a working apache2.conf and put this in your modules file section